# nodejs starting a new call stack

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following problem:

I have an array with functions, that I need to call one after the other:

`fun[0]()` then `fun[1]()` ...

Since these functions make asynchronous calls, I can't just write

```
fun[0]();
fun[1]();
```

Therefore I addded at the 'end' of each function in the array a call to the next function.

This actually works, but this results in growing the stack.
Example:

```
function fun0(){
   fun[1](); // now fun[1] is added to the stack
}
```

Is there a way to avoid this problem? I don't need the local variables of the other functions.

Comment: look up 'promises'. That way you can easily pipe asynchronous calls. I don't use nodejs often enough to explain it here but there are good resources. A nice intro to it: http://davidshariff.com/blog/futures-and-promises-in-javascript/

Comment: You really should read more on treating asynchronicity in JS. I found this [explanation of jQuery.Deferred @ HTML5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/async/deferred/) a good tutorial on this topic generally. Promise (also called future, e.g. in Java) is a design pattern that allows you to escape [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/), which usually pops up when writing async code otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
process.nextTick()
```

or

```
setInverval()
```

to achieve this

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on how to use those functions to solve the problem? Any pros and cons to use of either? Just names of functions don’t tell much about how you intend to use them in this scenario, how they answer the question. Questions can be closed as “unclear what you’re asking” – this answer is pretty much “unclear what you’re answering”.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way around.

You can use the async.js
https://github.com/caolan/async

Install it using `npm install async`

Then if you want to execute functions one after the another, there is a method,

```
async.series([
    function(callback){
        // do some stuff ...
        callback(null, 'one');
    },
    function(callback){
        // do some more stuff ...
        callback(null, 'two');
    }
],
// optional callback
function(err, results){
    // results is now equal to ['one', 'two']
});
```

The second function only executes when the first one has issued the callback.
Hence this makes sure all functions inside the async.series execute one after the another.

Comment: hey, thx for your answer. by looking at async I found out the actually process.nextTick() and setInverval() do what I want.